# column _id does not exist

Tags: android, database, eclipse, sqlite

the error in my logcat is such

Logcat

```
08-29 08:20:57.961: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1766): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{one.two/one.two.Booking}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist
08-29 08:20:57.961: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1766):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2268)
08-29 08:20:57.961: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1766):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2284)
08-29 08:20:57.961: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1766):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:112)
08-29 08:20:57.961: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1766):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1692)
08-29 08:20:57.961: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1766):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-29 08:20:57.961: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1766):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-29 08:20:57.961: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1766):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3948)
08-29 08:20:57.961: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1766):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-29 08:20:57.961: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1766):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-29 08:20:57.961: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1766):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:782)
08-29 08:20:57.961: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1766):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:540)
08-29 08:20:57.961: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1766):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-29 08:20:57.961: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1766): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist
08-29 08:20:57.961: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1766):     at android.database.AbstractCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AbstractCursor.java:314)
08-29 08:20:57.961: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1766):     at android.widget.CursorAdapter.init(CursorAdapter.java:111)
08-29 08:20:57.961: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1766):     at android.widget.CursorAdapter.<init>(CursorAdapter.java:90)
08-29 08:20:57.961: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1766):     at android.widget.ResourceCursorAdapter.<init>(ResourceCursorAdapter.java:47)
08-29 08:20:57.961: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1766):     at android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.<init>(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:85)
08-29 08:20:57.961: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1766):     at one.two.Booking.onCreate(Booking.java:34)
08-29 08:20:57.961: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1766):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1123)
08-29 08:20:57.961: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1766):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2231)
```

Part of my DBAdapter.java

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        db = new DBAdapter(this);
        db.open();
        setContentView(R.layout.booking);
        /*long id; 
        id = db.insertTime(
        new String("08:00")); */
        Cursor spinnerCursor = db.getSpinnerData(); 
        startManagingCursor(spinnerCursor);
        Spinner colourSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
```

Creation of DB

```
package one.two;


import java.io.IOException;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DBAdapter 
{   
    private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/one.two/databases/"; 
    private static String DB_NAME = "irsyad";

    //values for the login table
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_USERNAME = "Username";
    public static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "Password";
    public static final String KEY_LNAME = "LastName";
    public static final String KEY_FNAME ="FirstName";

    public static final String KEY_ROWID2 = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_STATUS = "status";
    public static final String KEY_DESTINATION = "destination";
    public static final String KEY_ARRIVAL = "arrival";
    public static final String KEY_FERRY ="ferry";

    private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";

    //declare Database name, tables names
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "irsyad";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "User";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE_2 = "port";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    //declares the rules for the database tables
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
        "create table user (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + "Username text not null, Password text not null,"
        + "LastName text not null, FirstName text not null);";

    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_2 =
        "create table port (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + "status text null, destination text null,"
        + "arrival text null, ferry text null);";

    private final Context context; 

    private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    public DBAdapter(Context ctx) 
    {
        this.context = ctx;
        DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
    {
        DatabaseHelper(Context context) 
        {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        //Create the tables with the rules we set.
        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
        {
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_2);
        }

        //OnUpgrade is only for use when u changed the database's version to 2 etc.
        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, 
        int newVersion) 
        {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion 
                    + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS port");
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }    

    //---opens the database---
    public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException 
    {
        db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    //---closes the database---    
    public void close() 
    {
        DBHelper.close();
    }

    //Method for inserting login details, can be used in other java files when DBAdapter is
    //declared in the java file. e.g. DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
    public long insertUser(String Username, String Password, String LastName, String FirstName) 
    {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_USERNAME, Username);
        initialValues.put(KEY_PASSWORD, Password);
        initialValues.put(KEY_LNAME, LastName);
        initialValues.put(KEY_FNAME, FirstName);
        return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }
   /* public long insertTime(String arrival) 
    { 
    ContentValues initialValue = new ContentValues(); 
    initialValue.put(KEY_ARRIVAL, arrival); 
    return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE_2, KEY_ARRIVAL, initialValue); 
    }*/

    //---deletes a particular title---
    public boolean deleteUser(long rowId) 
    {
        return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + 
                "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }

    //method for retrieving all the inputs from database
    public Cursor getAllUser() 
    {
        return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
                KEY_ROWID, 
                KEY_USERNAME,
                KEY_PASSWORD,
                KEY_LNAME,
                KEY_FNAME,},
                null, 
                null, 
                null, 
                null, 
                null);
    }   

    public Cursor getAllData() 
    {
        return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE_2, new String[] {
                KEY_ROWID2, 
                KEY_STATUS,
                KEY_DESTINATION,
                KEY_ARRIVAL,
                KEY_FERRY,},
                null, 
                null, 
                null, 
                null, 
                null);
    }   

    //---retrieves a particular title---
    public Cursor getUser(long rowId) throws SQLException 
    {
        Cursor mCursor =
                db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
                        KEY_ROWID,
                        KEY_USERNAME, 
                        KEY_PASSWORD,
                        KEY_LNAME,
                        KEY_FNAME,}, 
                        KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, 
                        null,
                        null, 
                        null, 
                        null, 
                        null);
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;
    }

    public Cursor getSpinnerData() throws SQLException 
    {
        Cursor mCursor =
                db.query(DATABASE_TABLE_2, new String[] {               
                        KEY_ARRIVAL,}, 
                        null,
                        null, 
                        null, 
                        null, 
                        null);
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;
    }

    //---updates a title---
    public boolean updateUser(long rowId, String Username, String Password, String LastName, String FirstName)
    {
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put(KEY_USERNAME, Username);
        args.put(KEY_PASSWORD, Password);
        args.put(KEY_LNAME, LastName);
        args.put(KEY_FNAME, FirstName);
        return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, 
                         KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }

    private boolean checkDataBase()
    {

        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        try
        {
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

        }
        catch(SQLiteException e)
        {
            //database does't exist yet.
        }

        if(checkDB != null)
        {
            checkDB.close();
        }

        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    public void createDataBase() throws IOException
    {

        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

        if(dbExist)
        {
            //do nothing - database already exist
        }
        else
        {
             db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
             db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_2);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are not including `_id` in your column list for the query you do in `getSpinnerData()`.

Comment: This answer spared me quite a bit of confusion ><

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a column in your table called _id integer alphanumeric.

Comment: Double check your database, and check exactly what table are you querying. Also make sure the database got updated (you need to increase the version number). The answer is correct.

Comment: Im updating to the correct version i suppose. And i am also querying table port. So i don't really understand where the problem lies.