# Converting an ArrayAdapter to CursorAdapter for use in a SearchView

Tags: android, android-actionbar, simplecursoradapter, autocompletetextview, android-cursoradapter

How can I convert an `ArrayAdapter<String>` of static data into a `CursorAdapter` for using  Suggestion Listener in `SearchView`? 
I have constructed the `ArrayAdapter<String>` from static data (`allString`)

```
ArrayAdapter<String> searchAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, R.layout.listitem, allString);
```

and I use it for an `MultiAutoCompleteTextView` which works fine in devices with API level less than 11

```
MultiAutoCompleteTextView findTextView.setAdapter(searchAdapter);
```

However my target API is level is 11 and for API>10 I use an `ActionBar` within which I would like to have a SearchView instead.

Here's what I have tried: It does show the `ActionBar` with the embedded `SearchView` but does not give any suggestions as it would in the `MultiAutoCompleteTextView`.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {     
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();

         if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 10){
             inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu11, menu);
             searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.MENU_SEARCH).getActionView();
             int[] to = {0};
             CursorAdapter cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(context, R.layout.listitem, null, allBusStopString, to);
             searchView.setSuggestionsAdapter(cursorAdapter);
             searchView.setOnSuggestionListener(new OnSuggestionListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onSuggestionClick(int position) {
                    String selectedItem = (String)cursorAdapter.getItem(position);
                    Log.v("search view", selectedItem);
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onSuggestionSelect(int position) {
                    return false;
                }
             });  
         }else{
             inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
         }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

That's strange `SearchView.setSuggestionsAdapter` accepts CursorAdapter only.

You could create [MatrixCursor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/MatrixCursor.html) and fill it with data from String array. I hope you have small data collection.

Then pass the cursor to CursorAdapter.

```
String[] columnNames = {"_id","text"}
MatrixCursor cursor = new MatrixCursor(columnNames);
String[] array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.allStrings); //if strings are in resources
String[] temp = new String[2];
int id = 0;
for(String item : array){
    temp[0] = Integer.toString(id++);
        temp[1] = item;
    cursor.addRow(temp);
}               
String[] from = {"text"}; 
int[] to = {R.id.name_entry};
busStopCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(context, R.layout.listentry, cursor, from, to);
```

Comment: I just had to add _id column to avoid the error explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360605/column-id-does-not-exist)

Comment: Yes indeed, I forgot about `_id`

Comment: The searchView seems to work fine but the Suggestions are wrong. it always shows all of the string entries, no matter what I type in search box. Aren't suggestions supposed to work like AutocompleteTextView or am I missing somthing?

Comment: I think you have to set `OnQueryTextListener`, recreate the cursor in this listener and change the cursor in adapter.

Comment: yes, I did the `OnQueryTextListener` with my own autocomplete method and it works now. thanks

Comment: @BehzadMomahedHeravi: I am doing same thing but dont know how to do it with my Custom Content Provider. I want to filter Songs available in My Device. can you please help me for that?

Comment: Nice One. I got Solution of what i want.

Comment: how to filter the results on text change?

Comment: This should have not been the accepted answer. So for the newcomers i would strictly advice to look at the @kosiara - Bartosz Kosarzycki's answer below.

Comment: what is R.id.name_entry ? @pawelzieba

Answer (score 17):

I was facing similar problem. You can use **SearchView.setSuggestionsAdapter()** which only accepts **CursorAdapter**. On the other hand... what's the point? If you use the standard `<android.support.v7.widget.SearchView />` then it contains SearchAutoComplete which extends AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView inside. The following code worked for me:

```
List<String> items = Lists.newArrayList(new String[] {"aaaaa", "bbbbb", "ccccc", "ddddd"});
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.autocomplete_searchview);
SearchView.SearchAutoComplete searchSrcTextView = (SearchView.SearchAutoComplete) findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
searchSrcTextView.setThreshold(1);
searchSrcTextView.setAdapter(new SuggestionAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, items));
searchSrcTextView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        return;
    }
});
```

and the following Adapter code:

```
public class SuggestionAdapter<T> extends ArrayAdapter<T> {

    private List<T> items;
    private List<T> filteredItems;
    private ArrayFilter mFilter;

    public SuggestionAdapter(Context context, @LayoutRes int resource, @NonNull List<T> objects) {
        super(context, resource, Lists.<T>newArrayList());
        this.items = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public T getItem(int position) {
        return items.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (mFilter == null) {
            mFilter = new ArrayFilter();
        }
        return mFilter;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        //todo: change to pattern-size
        return items.size();
    }

    private class ArrayFilter extends Filter {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence prefix) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            //custom-filtering of results
            results.values = items;
            results.count = items.size();

            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            filteredItems = (List<T>) results.values;
            if (results.count > 0) {
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This returns everything no matter what you type

Comment: This is the best solution if you haven't got a real cursor (fill a cursor 'manually' is a bad patch). It's working for me now, but I needed to change some of the example code:

- Make findViewById for the searchAutoComplete like searchView.findViewById

- Override getItems and getCounts of the adapter, use filteredItems instead items

- It's obvious that you need to implement your filter logic, like the comment '//custom-filtering of results' saids.

Thanks a lot for the example code!

Comment: This is perfect Im working with an elastic search endpoint I will just fetch the data and reset the adapter when I get new search results.