# How to set adapter to searchview in actionbar

Tags: android, searchview

Setting custom values to `Searchview Adapter`

like we do in autocomplete and passing array string

I tried this code:

```
private void setupSearchView(MenuItem searchItem) {

    if (isAlwaysExpanded()) {
        mSearchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
    } else {
        searchItem.setShowAsActionFlags(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW);
    }

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    if (searchManager != null) {
        List<SearchableInfo> searchables = searchManager.getSearchablesInGlobalSearch();
        SearchableInfo info = searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName());
        for (SearchableInfo inf : searchables) {
            if (inf.getSuggestAuthority() != null && inf.getSuggestAuthority().startsWith("applications")) {
                info = inf;
            }
        }
        mSearchView.setSearchableInfo(info);

    }
    mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
}
```

Comment: pls don't suggest me to use custom layout and setting it to action bar with defining xml file :)

Comment: see this link http://looksok.wordpress.com/2013/06/15/android-searchview-tutorial-edittext-with-phone-contacts-search-and-autosuggestion/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`SearchView` takes a `CursorAdapter` only:

- [`setSuggestionsAdapter(CursorAdapter adapter)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.html#setSuggestionsAdapter%28android.widget.CursorAdapter%29)

Unfortunately that means you can't just supply an `ArrayAdapter` with an array of items. If you really wanted to use a `String[]` as searchable data source, I suppose you could wrap it into a [`MatrixCursor`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/MatrixCursor.html).

An example is can be found here:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/11628527/1029225

Answer (score 4):

Please go through these links. You will get it what you want.

http://looksok.wordpress.com/2013/06/15/android-searchview-tutorial-edittext-with-phone-contacts-search-and-autosuggestion/

http://innovativenetsolutions.com/2013/07/android-tutorial-search-interface-search-dialog/

http://www.thaicreate.com/mobile/android-searchview.html

https://www.grokkingandroid.com/android-tutorial-adding-search-to-your-apps/

Comment: http://innovativenetsolutions.com/2013/07/android-tutorial-search-interface-search-dialog/ was nice