# How to set custom row layout for android searchView suggestion list

Tags: android, searchview

I am using searchView and searchable.xml to search phone contacts.

searchable.xml

```
  android:searchMode="queryRewriteFromText"
  android:searchSuggestAuthority="com.android.contacts"
  android:searchSuggestIntentAction= "android.provider.Contacts.SEARCH_SUGGESTION_CLICKED"
  android:searchSuggestIntentData= "content://com.android.contacts/contacts/lookup"
```

So, when I search any keyword, it displays suggestion list of matched contacts of phone (matched keywords highlighted in Blue color).

I did not use any custom adapter or custom list item layout. It displays result list in default android style.

How can I change the style of searchView (background, hint text color, hint text font, search icon etc.) and how to apply custom layout for result list items.

Note: I am getting matching contact names from native contacts database. I did not write any query to fetch the result.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19330912/how-to-set-adapter-to-searchview-in-actionbar