# SearchView performs network query : Should we capture user input via SearchView.OnQueryTextListener, or intent filter Activity

Tags: android

Currently, I tend to use `SearchView` in `ActionBar`'s action view, to perform network query when user performs typing. The returned network result will tend present in `SearchView` drop down with custom layout.

After looking at

- [Converting an ArrayAdapter to CursorAdapter for use in a SearchView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11628172/converting-an-arrayadapter-to-cursoradapter-for-use-in-a-searchview)
- http://ramannanda.blogspot.com/2014/10/android-searchview-integration-with.html

I think I can achieve my purpose by using the following steps.

1. Capture user input in `SearchView.OnQueryTextListener`, and perform async network query.
2. Once we get result from async network query, build `MatrixCursor` to hold network query result.
3. Build `SimpleCursorAdapter` around MatrixCursor, for custom drop down layout.

However, after further reading

- http://www.edumobile.org/android/action-bar-search-view/
- http://karanbalkar.com/2014/06/tutorial-84-implement-searchview-in-android/
- http://developer.android.com/training/search/setup.html

I realize another way to capture user input, is through `SearchManager`, by setting up an intent filter `Activity`, of `android.intent.action.SEARCH`.

I was wondering, for my use case, which is the more appropriate method? Should we capture user input via SearchView.OnQueryTextListener, or intent filter `Activity`?

Comment: What approach did you end up taking? I went down the SearchView.OnQueryTexListener route and fired a loader to update the SearchView's suggestions adapter.