# Column '_id' does not exist

Tags: android, sqlite, join

I have seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360605/column-id-does-not-exist) and it did not give me answer in my situation.

I am using ready library([SQLiteAssetHelper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper)) for copying SQLite database from assets forder and opening that database from data/data/[package]/databases/. Now I want to get values of 3 joined tables.

> entry(id,ent_seq); sense(id,fk); gloss(id,fk,lang,value);

Using this method to get joined table:

```
 public Cursor getJoinedInfo(String lookingFor)
        {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "DB: looking up info");

            SQLiteDatabase db=getReadableDatabase();

            Cursor cursor;
            String query;

            query="SELECT " +
                    " e.id," +
                    " s.id," +
                    " s.fk," +
                    " g.id," +
                    " g.fk," +
                    " g.lang," +
                    " g.lang" +
                    " FROM entry e" +
                    "     INNER JOIN sense s ON e.id = s.fk" +
                    "     INNER JOIN gloss g ON s.id = g.fk" +
                    " WHERE g.value like '%"+lookingFor+"%'";

            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "DB: query = \n" + query.replace(", ",",\n  "));
            cursor=db.rawQuery(query,null);
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "DB: query complete");

            return cursor;      
        }
```

Now it is giving this error:

> 08-09 22:26:16.632: E/AndroidRuntime(9842): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist

What should I do? Please give your suggestions.

Full stacktrace:

```
08-09 23:23:43.015: I/ApplicationPackageManager(11446): cscCountry is not German : SKZ
08-09 23:23:45.031: D/myLogs(11446): d
08-09 23:23:45.031: D/myLogs(11446): DB: looking up info
08-09 23:23:45.109: I/SQLiteAssetHelper(11446): successfully opened database akita
08-09 23:23:45.117: D/myLogs(11446): DB: query = 
08-09 23:23:45.117: D/myLogs(11446): SELECT  e.id,
08-09 23:23:45.117: D/myLogs(11446):   s.id,
08-09 23:23:45.117: D/myLogs(11446):   s.fk,
08-09 23:23:45.117: D/myLogs(11446):   g.id,
08-09 23:23:45.117: D/myLogs(11446):   g.fk,
08-09 23:23:45.117: D/myLogs(11446):   g.lang,
08-09 23:23:45.117: D/myLogs(11446):   g.lang FROM entry e     INNER JOIN sense s ON e.id = s.fk     INNER JOIN gloss g ON s.id = g.fk WHERE g.value like '%d%'
08-09 23:23:45.117: D/myLogs(11446): DB: query complete
08-09 23:23:45.117: W/dalvikvm(11446): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)
08-09 23:23:45.203: E/AndroidRuntime(11446): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-09 23:23:45.203: E/AndroidRuntime(11446): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist
08-09 23:23:45.203: E/AndroidRuntime(11446):    at android.database.AbstractCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AbstractCursor.java:314)
08-09 23:23:45.203: E/AndroidRuntime(11446):    at android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter.init(CursorAdapter.java:174)
08-09 23:23:45.203: E/AndroidRuntime(11446):    at android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter.<init>(CursorAdapter.java:151)
08-09 23:23:45.203: E/AndroidRuntime(11446):    at android.support.v4.widget.ResourceCursorAdapter.<init>(ResourceCursorAdapter.java:93)
08-09 23:23:45.203: E/AndroidRuntime(11446):    at android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.<init>(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:89)
08-09 23:23:45.203: E/AndroidRuntime(11446):    at com.joericharduz.akita.MainActivity.displayListView(MainActivity.java:77)
08-09 23:23:45.203: E/AndroidRuntime(11446):    at com.joericharduz.akita.MainActivity.access$0(MainActivity.java:68)
08-09 23:23:45.203: E/AndroidRuntime(11446):    at com.joericharduz.akita.MainActivity$1.onTextChanged(MainActivity.java:56)
08-09 23:23:45.203: E/AndroidRuntime(11446):    at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:6603)
08-09 23:23:45.203: E/AndroidRuntime(11446):    at android.widget.TextView.handleTextChanged(TextView.java:6650)
08-09 23:23:45.203: E/AndroidRuntime(11446):    at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onTextChanged(TextView.java:6794)
08-09 23:23:45.203: E/AndroidRuntime(11446):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendTextChange(SpannableStringBuilder.java:889)
08-09 23:23:45.203: E/AndroidRuntime(11446):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.change(SpannableStringBuilder.java:352)
08-09 23:23:45.203: E/AndroidRuntime(11446):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.change(SpannableStringBuilder.java:269)
08-09 23:23:45.203: E/AndroidRuntime(11446):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:432)
08-09 23:23:45.203: E/AndroidRuntime(11446):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:409)
08-09 23:23:45.203: E/AndroidRuntime(11446):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:28)
08-09 23:23:45.203: E/AndroidRuntime(11446):    at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.replaceText(BaseInputConnection.java:654)
08-09 23:23:45.203: E/AndroidRuntime(11446):    at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.commitText(BaseInputConnection.java:180)
08-09 23:23:45.203: E/AndroidRuntime(11446):    at com.android.internal.widget.EditableInputConnection.commitText(EditableInputConnection.java:120)
08-09 23:23:45.203: E/AndroidRuntime(11446):    at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:283)
08-09 23:23:45.203: E/AndroidRuntime(11446):    at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:79)
08-09 23:23:45.203: E/AndroidRuntime(11446):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-09 23:23:45.203: E/AndroidRuntime(11446):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
08-09 23:23:45.203: E/AndroidRuntime(11446):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
08-09 23:23:45.203: E/AndroidRuntime(11446):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-09 23:23:45.203: E/AndroidRuntime(11446):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-09 23:23:45.203: E/AndroidRuntime(11446):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
08-09 23:23:45.203: E/AndroidRuntime(11446):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
08-09 23:23:45.203: E/AndroidRuntime(11446):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Are you sure the error is from this block of code?  If you post the full stacktrace, it will tell you the offending file and line number.  Also, what are you doing with the data after the cursor is returned?

Comment: @MattDavis, my guess is he's using the Cursor in a CursorAdapter, which expects an `_id` column.

Comment: @MattDavis I sure about error is because of this method.Before adding this method there was not such error. I added full stacktrace.

Comment: @323go You are right, I am using SimpleCursorAdapter to put retrieved values into ListView. Can you tell me what should be changed in order to solve this problem?